# What would have to happen for the world's oxygen to decrease at an alarming rate?

Tags: oxygen

What would have to happen for Earth's oxygen to decrease at an alarming rate and furthermore be dangerously low or completely gone in a year?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Sebastian*! It would be nice if you could [edit] your question to expand a bit on why you need this and what defines "dangerously low" for you. Dangerously low for humans? Or do you just want "completely gone"? One-line questions are often not well received because they look like a lack of effort on the side of the person asking. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Please see the answer @Slarty pointed and then edit your Question to state what is your world . The easiest (but probably not what you need) would need some condition setting most of world forests on fire. Next is something interfering with photosynthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Stop producing oxigen.

Oxigen is so reactive, you can't have a supply without something that releases it constantly. Hind plants and plankton hability to release oxigen and the numbers will fall down fairly quick. UV blocking material clouds, a virus that breaks the clorofila reaction... you name it. Stop the engine, and the factory falls silent.

Answer (score 4):

Scorched Earth - literally. I'm not quite able to do all the math, but I'm pretty sure that if all the biomass on our planet were consumed in a huge fire, most if not all the oxygen in our atmosphere would be converted to carbon dioxide. I also think this is likely to be one of the fastest ways this could happen.

Comment: This also happens to neatly get rid of most plant life that would replenish the oxygen post-blaze.

Answer (score 0):

A massive release of Iron in oceans, via e.g. tectonic processes.

Iron binds oxygen, [forming iron oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event#Tectonic_trigger) (that's how we get iron ores). This consumes a lot of oxygen.

Augment it with [carbonate-bicarbonate process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_acidification#Mechanism) that flushes carbon monoxide out of atmoshpere and into the ocean, and plants don't have enough CO2 to replenish oxygen with.

Comment: Seriously? "Stop producing oxygen" and "Burn some forests" are better answers? Is this a kindergarden writing club?

Comment: All answers have room for improvement - that's what the comments are for. So that we can point out things that others may have missed, with the ultimate goal of answering OP's question satisfactorily. Dissing other answers just because yours was less popular is frankly immature and unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Without going the evil aliens route a flashburn of the planet would be the "easy way" to do it. Otherwise the only thing that could crash O2 would be a meteorite made of something really reactive grazing the atmosphere like Ruthenium+8 that sucks up oxygen at a rate of 4-to-1 but it would have to ablate megatonnes of material into the atmosphere to make an appreciable difference.